# The LINQ expression could not be translated (Generic class)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I've seen a dozen of these questions here on SO, but none of them were really of any help to me, so I decided to post another one, to try and fix my issue.

I have a class `GenericRepository<T>` which serves as a template for basic `CRUD` methods, because I have a relatively big model package, so I didn't want to implement the same method for different classes over and over again (Don't repeat yourself).

The problem arose when I tried to create a custom method for querying using a `Predicate<T>`.
Here is my code:

```
        public IEnumerable<T> GetMatching(Predicate<T> condition)
             => dbContext.Set<T>.Where(entity => condition(entity));
```

In my mind, the purpose of this was to be able to pass any kind of a query, to have it evaluated and given back as results.

Here is the part where I tried to fetch some `Doctor` objects by filtering them using a field named `EmployeeID`:

```
Repository.GetMatching(doctor => doctor.EmployeeID > 10);
```

The idea was, to give me back a list of doctors, which have their `EmployeeID` number field greater than 10.
Unfortunately, this gave me the following error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Doctor>
.Where(d => Invoke(__condition_0, d[Doctor]))' could not be translated. 
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client 
evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either 
AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

According to the error message, I tried to add `ToList()` at the end of the `GetMatching()` function, but to no awail, it still failed with the same error message.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `Predicate` take an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, and then pass that in directly:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetMatching(Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition)
         => dbContext.Set<T>.Where(condition);
```

The reason for this is that Entity Framework relies on expression trees to determine how to translate LINQ code into a SQL query. When the expression it's evaluating (the lambda you pass in to Where) calls a function that Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate (like an arbitrary delegate that someone passed into your function), it chokes.

On a side note, be thoughtful about the fact that returning an `IEnumerable<T>` will make any additional LINQ code added on to the returned value get treated as LINQ-to-Objects, rather than being evaluated by Entity Framework. If this is what you're going for, consider calling `.ToList()` and returning something like `IReadOnlyCollection<>` to avoid delaying execution unnecessarily. If not, consider returning `IQueryable<>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for an amazing answer, you've saved my hours of time :)

Comment: If I may ask, what exactly do you mean by "To avoid delaying execution unnecessarily"? Is returning `IEnumerable<T>` slowing down my program?

Comment: @ForWiz: If the returned `IEnumerable<>` doesn't get evaluated until after the dbContext is disposed, you'll get an exception. If it doesn't get evaluated until after you've made changes in the database, those changes will be reflected in the returned results (see [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-example)). If the code consuming this method assumes that the matching items will be loaded from the database before the method returns, you should force that to happen to avoid unexpected behavior.

Comment: Regarding performance, if you add `.Where()` or `.GroupBy()` to the results of `GetMatching()`, those operations are likely going to be far more efficient at the database layer. So coercing your `IQueryable<>` into an `IEnumerable<>` may be slowing down your program. But due to delayed execution, if you measure the performance of calling GetMatching(), it will appear to be blazingly fast, because it's doing practically nothing. But some later code that iterates over the results will go slowly because that's where the database call (and subsequent LINQ operations) will be getting invoked.